Jest.mock() in another file
I have a CRA-rewired typescript react app.
Jest is imported globally.
In order to use jest mocks I have to write
jest.mock('module-name') ABOVE describe() block and IN THE same file, e.g.
import { act, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';
import { something } from 'my-module';

// 150 of my 300 test suites contain these.
// THERE IS NO IMPLEMENTATION and automock is fine 
// BUT ONLY IF I opt-in. 
// The other 150 test suites might have an implementation;
// Or they might use REAL modules and not mocks. 
// This is why I don't want to just turn on `autoMock`.
// And I don't want to add this to `testSetup.js` because the OTHER 150 
// do not need them.
// But I want to find a way to call something like `TestUtilities.mockStandard()` for the first 150 test suites.
jest.mock('my-module');
jest.mock('my-module2');
jest.mock('my-module3');
jest.mock('my-module4');
jest.mock('my-module5');
jest.mock('my-module6');
jest.mock('my-module7');

describe('MyComponent', () => {
    afterAll(() => {
        jest.unmock('my-module');
        jest.unmock('my-module2');
        jest.unmock('my-module3');
        jest.unmock('my-module4');
        jest.unmock('my-module5');
        jest.unmock('my-module6');
        jest.unmock('my-module7');
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        jest.resetAllMocks();
        jest.useRealTimers();
    });

    test('component renders', async () => {
        (something as jest.MockedFunction<typeof something>).mockImplementation(() => 'banana');
        const { container } = render(<MyComponent></MyComponent>);
        expect(screen.queryByText('banana')).toBeVisible();
    });
});

Now I have a few hundred test suites and thousands of tests.
Some of them have COMMON things I want to mock (like my-module), but not ALL.
So I don't want to use testSetup.js to mock the modules in ALL tests, but I DO WANT to find a way to not have to write jest.mock() over and over again.
So I tried creating a utilities module like so:
const TestUtilities = {
    mockMyModule: () => {
        jest.mock('my-module');
    },

    unmockMyModule: () => {
        jest.unmock('my-module');
    },
};

export default TestUtilities;

and then modified the original test:
import { act, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';
import { something } from 'my-module';
import TestUtilities from './TestUtilities';

TestUtilities.mockMyModule();

describe('MyComponent', () => {
    afterAll(() => {
        TestUtilities.unmockMyModule();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        jest.resetAllMocks();
        jest.useRealTimers();
    });

    test('component renders', async () => {
        (something as jest.MockedFunction<typeof something>).mockImplementation(() => 'banana');
        const { container } = render(<MyComponent></MyComponent>);
        expect(screen.queryByText('banana')).toBeVisible();
    });
});

Unfortunately now test behaves as if my-module is not mocked :(
Is there a way to re-use those jest.mock() blocks?

jest.mock needs to be in the same scope as the import of the mocked module, so something easy to try is import the mocked module inside your utility and also provide a means to access the imported module so it can be used in the tests. Calling methods off your utility is not much different than using jest.mock though.

Try jest.doMock()

@LinDu good suggestion. unfortunately, didn't work, the code still behaves as if the module is not mocked.

@morganney But that won't really work with code under test as that will not be calling module from my test utility?

@zaitsman I’m not sure what you’re saying. Words are so vague compared to code . Overall though, I don’t see the real benefit to calling mock from a utility vs right in the test case. You still have to add code to each test case you want to mock. Can you provide a link to your project on GitHub? I might take a look if so.

@morganney Most of those hundreds of tests mock the same 5 modules the same 5 ways. (i18n, router, authentication etc.) for default useXXX hooks. If I could collapse even 500 lines into 100 lines across a bunch of files that's a noticeable saving in dev experience

So use a __mocks__ dir to provide the manual mocks and then accept you still have to call jest.mock where you want them mocked, but you don’t have to provide the mock implementation over and over. That is if one manual mock works for all test cases. You can also read some global var inside the manual mock to provide conditional mocking.

@morganney that really doesn't save anything because those implementations are usually one liners or non-specified (e.g. simple jest.mock('whatever') as automock). And no, I don't want ALL modules automocked by default, I just want the dependencies that are common to my root/page components to not have to be jest.mock(); over and over. __mocks__ is only useful when there is re-usable implementation.

Again, you should expand your example code to provide more details because if you require contextual mocks dependent upon the test case, I fail to see how a utility simply wrapping jest.mock helps. Previously you said Most of those hundreds of tests mock the same 5 modules the same 5 ways. now you seem to be saying the opposite. Double check the example of manual mocks in the docs.

@morganney please see edit. Honestly I have what I feel is a trivial requirement.

All or none is easy, but your requirement of some this way some that way makes it not trivial. I still think you should try using a manual mock in the __mocks__ dir adjacent to module-n and then for the 150 tests that require special mocking implementations use a global var set in the test case and read by the manual mock to change the mocked module. For the other 150 that can use the auto mock behavior just don’t set any global vars in the tests.

So in the end the answer lies within the evil depths of javascript's eval.
Specifically, we need to create a typescript module that will run the jest.mock() as eval WHILE it is being loaded.
Then jest runner will understand the mock calls in the correct context.
For my OP example, the common module looks like this:
let mockCall = `(() => {
    jest.mock('my-module');
    jest.mock('my-module2');
    jest.mock('my-module4');
    jest.mock('my-module3');
    jest.mock('my-module5');
    jest.mock('my-module7');
    jest.mock('my-module6');
})()`;
eval(mockCall);

export const CommonMocksModule = {
    unmock() {
        jest.unmock('my-module');
        jest.unmock('my-module2');
        jest.unmock('my-module3');
        jest.unmock('my-module4');
        jest.unmock('my-module5');
        jest.unmock('my-module6');
        jest.unmock('my-module7');
    }
}

And the spec becomes:
// So I put this first, but really it should just go before the
// first time any of `my-moduleX` are imported 
// otherwise that import will be set and `jest.mock()` won't overwrite it.
// IMPORTANT!! we need to reference `unmock` call 
// otherwise import is not run by jest
import { CommonMocksModule } from "./_commonMocks";

import { act, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';
import { something } from 'my-module';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
    afterAll(() => {
        CommonMocksModule.unmock();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        jest.resetAllMocks();
        jest.useRealTimers();
    });

    test('component renders', async () => {
        (something as jest.MockedFunction<typeof something>).mockImplementation(() => 'banana');
        const { container } = render(<MyComponent></MyComponent>);
        expect(screen.queryByText('banana')).toBeVisible();
    });
});

Achieving our ultimate goal of saving on all the repeated jest.mock()

Seems you have half the test cases that are ok with the default mock implementation, and the other half that require special implementations.
If that is the case, you might want to try something like the following.
Assuming a directory structure like this:
.
└── src/
    └── modules/
        ├── dependency-n.js
        ├── __mocks__/
        │   └── dependency-n.js
        ├── dependent.js
        └── dependent.test.js

Manual mocks with global vars
You can use global variables defined within tests to alter the behavior of the mock implementation of the manual mocks.
mocks/dependency-n.js
let mocked = jest.fn();

if (globals.useAltMockForDepN) {
  mocked = jest.fn(() => {
    // Your custom mocking implementation based on calling test
  })
}

export default mocked;

dependent.test.js
import { something } from 'dependency-n';

jest.mock('dependency-n');

describe('MyDependentComponent', () => {
    afterAll(() => {
        jest.unmock('dependency-module-n');
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        // Possibly use in afterAll instead
        globals.useAltMockForDepN = false
    });

    test('component renders', async () => {
        // Possibly use in beforeAll
        globals.useAltMockForDepN = true;

        // Now do your testing
    });
});

This really only saves you from needing custom mock implementations in half of your tests, and you still have to make calls to jest.mock() in all your tests unless you are willing/able to mock every imported module, then you can set automock: true. If you do want to use automock: true then you won't need to call jest.mock() in your tests, but then you'll be required to call jest.unmock() for all the imported modules you don't want mocked.

I have what I feel is a trivial requirement.

Your scenario is not an all or nothing one, so you have to write code to distinguish between your special cases, there's no way around it unfortunately.
TestUtilities
The call to jest.mock() and the import need to be in the same scope and currently you are not importing the mocked module in your test utilities.
You can try making these changes.
import myModule from 'my-module'

const TestUtilities = {
    mockMyModule: () => {
        jest.mock('my-module');
    },

    unmockMyModule: () => {
        jest.unmock('my-module');
    },
   
    getMyMockedModule: () => myModule,

};

export default TestUtilities;


You haven’t really provided a reproducible example but I wanted to put my comments into some code to try and help.

Please check out my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78469514/2057955
I wasn't too happy with the globals idea as I am not confident how will this run when test suites are run in parallel, plus it was still a lot more manual than simply telling all devs add this to your spec if you want all our common stuff mocked

Interesting solution. I generally don't think of solutions involving eval but seeing as this is a test environment running on a CI server somewhere unexposed to end users it's unlikely for malicious code to sneak in somehow. Regarding the globals, as long as your tests perform proper cleanup everything should be fine as the parallel tests are run in separate processes. Glad you found something that worked for you and your team though.
